# Append to File performance and odd behavior

Tags: powershell

I am trying to performance profile different methods of appending to a log file, and I am seeing some odd behavior. Ideally I want to use the FileStream approach, because I want to be able to verify the path, which I can do with `$fileStream.name`. But I am seeing some odd behavior.

In this code, I get two blank lines echo'd to console after 'FileStream', even though the two `New-Object` lines are variable assignments. And more concerning, fileStreamFile.txt does not contain all the lines it should. It seems to stop at 841 every time.

My assumption is the issue is with the default buffer size, but I thought buffer size was related to individual writes, not overall file size. And further, if I change the line count to 10,000 it doesn't keep failing at 841, it goes farther but still doesn't complete.

Also, curious what differences I should be concerned with between `New-Object` vs `[io.streamWriter]::New`

```
Clear-Host

Write-Host 'FileStream'
Measure-Command {
    $fileStreamFile = "$env:TEMP\fileStreamFile.txt"
    $fileStream = New-Object io.fileStream $fileStreamFile, Append, Write, Read
    $fileWriter = New-Object io.streamWriter $fileStream
    foreach($i in 1..1000){
        $fileWriter.WriteLine($i)
    }
    $fileStream.Close(); $fileStream.Dispose()
}
#Remove-Item $fileStreamFile -force

Write-Host 'WriteStream'
Measure-Command {
    $WriteStreamFile = "$env:TEMP\writeStreamFile.txt"
    $writeStream = [io.streamWriter]::New($WriteStreamFile)
    foreach($i in 1..1000){
        $writeStream.WriteLine($i)
    }
    $writeStream.Close(); $writeStream.Dispose()
}
#Remove-Item $WriteStreamFile -force

Write-Host 'Add-Content'
Measure-Command {
    $addContentFile = "$env:TEMP\addContentFile.txt"
    foreach($i in 1..1000){
        Add-Content -path:$addContentFile  -value:$i
    }
}
#Remove-Item $addContentFile -force
Write-Host "`n`nDone"
```

Comment: You do not close `StreamWriter`, thus it have no opportunity to flush its buffer to file.

Comment: Doh! That's rather obvious in hindsight. #LearnSomethingNewEveryDay

Comment: It does beg the question, how do you ensure that every line writes in real time? I am using this for logging a long process, and while I want the log to be read-only during logging, I still need to be able to open it to look at that progress, and if it isn't complete. I had planned to create a script scope variable for the Writer, so I can reuse it for each writeLine, which could be half an hour apart. It seems like AutoFlush doesn't necessarily work. And adding a discrete flush to every write-in more than triples the time to completion, but still orders of magnitude better than Add-Content.

Comment: *And adding a discrete flush to every write-in more than triples the time to completion* That is why buffering exists in the first place.

Comment: As an aside: `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` (where both present) should generally be equivalent, and definitely are in the case of [`StreamWriter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,231) and [`Stream`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,240), so you only need _one_ call.

Comment: PetSerAl, that makes sense, and definitely points me at the right way to proceed.
mklement0, interesting, and it makes sense that you can't dispose of something that hasn't been closed. Just interesting that even well known people double up. I think even Microsoft's Scripting Guy does. Maybe old C habits like his formatting. But again, I know which way to go now.